# Error Undefined Procedure in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I wrote a rule:

```
parent(georgie,jessy) :-
   child(jessy,georgio).
```

but, when I want to prove

```
?- parent(georgie,jessy).
```

I get an error:

```
parent/2: Undefined procedure: child/2
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You need to add facts like `child(jessy, georgio).` to your program.

Comment: The head of the rule is what you want to prove; the body is what has to be true to prove that the rule is true. PS. You have a typo: georgio/georgie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the `child` relationship:

```
child(jessy, georgie).
```

Define the `parent` relationship to be opposite to the `child` relationship:

```
parent(X, Y) :- child(Y, X).
```

And test it.

```
?- parent(georgie, jessy).
true.
```